# How to Remove all content of a line after specific string. Non-Inclusive

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove all the contents of a line in notepad++ after targeting a specific string. My string also holds strange characters and I can't quite get a grip on regex to do this. Trying to target the string of "//-----------".

Here's an example of what I have:

```
//-----------comment a here
Code.dosomething = something

//-----------comment b here
Code.dosomething = something
```

Here's what I want to have post find and replace:

```
//-----------
Code.dosomething = something

//-----------
Code.dosomething = something
```

Comment: I.e. `^(//-----------).+`  =>  `$1`